# innerHTML - pass in value on (click) event

Tags: javascript, angular

How do I pass in a parameter to a click event that has been set in innerHTML?

**Component**

```
html = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <mark (click)='hello('my name is what')'>consectetur adipiscing elit</mark>"

constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngAfterContentChecked() {
  this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
   if (this.showcaseContentText.nativeElement.querySelector('mark')) {
     this.showcaseContentText.nativeElement
      .querySelector('mark')
      .addEventListener('click', this.hello.bind(this));
   }
}

hello(test: string) {
  console.log(test);
}
```

**Template**

```
<div class="text-md-left text-muted mb-lg-6" [innerHTML]="html" style="font-size: 15px"></div>
```

Comment: As this is Angular, why are you using `innerHTML`? You're meant to use the Virtual DOM rather than interacting with the DOM directly.

Comment: The HTML strings are being retrieved from an external API and this is the only way I could think of dummying it up locally

Comment: I'm confused then - if you're using an external web-service that returns HTML you want to render directly, why are you faffing around with `ngAfterContentChecked` and `ChangeDetectorRef`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm able to capture the `click` events from the `mark` tag using RxJS `fromEvent` instead of `addEventListener` and `AfterViewInit` instead of `AfterContentChecked` hook. I've also sanitized the HTML using Angular `DomSanitizer`.

Try the following

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { fromEvent, Subject } from "rxjs";
import { takeUntil } from "rxjs/operators";

...
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild("showcaseContentText") showcaseContentText: ElementRef<any>;
  html =
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <mark (click)='hello('my name is what')'>consectetur adipiscing elit</mark>";
  closed$ = new Subject<any>();

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
    fromEvent(
      this.showcaseContentText.nativeElement.querySelector("mark"),
      "click"
    )
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.closed$))
      .subscribe(e => console.log(e));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.closed$.next();
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<div #showcaseContentText class="text-md-left text-muted mb-lg-6" [innerHTML]="html | safe" style="font-size: 15px">
</div>
```

**safe.pipe.ts**

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Pipe({
  name: "safe",
  pure: true
})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  public transform(value: any): SafeHtml {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-o6244z?file=src/app/safe.pipe.ts)

#### Update: multiple `<mark>` tags in single `innerHTML`

In that case you could use `querySelectorAll()` instead of the `querySelector()` function. Also since there would be multiple elements, you could use `Array#map` along with `fromEvent` and use RxJS `map` operator to get the respective `id`s.

Note that we're create multiple subscription streams. So more the number of `mark` tags, more the number of streams. You need to close it when the component is closed (in the eg. `takeUntil` is used). There are better ways to handle multiple subscriptions (eg. using `combineLatest`), but they have their own pros and cons. I'll leave it to you to sort them out.

Controller

```js
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild("showcaseContentText") showcaseContentText: ElementRef<any>;
  html =
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <mark id='mark1' (click)='hello('my name is what')'>consectetur adipiscing elit</mark>. Lorem ipsum <mark id='mark2' (click)='hello('my name is two')'>dolor sit amet</mark>, consectetur adipiscing elit";
  closed$ = new Subject<any>();

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
    const obs$ = Array.from(
      this.showcaseContentText.nativeElement.querySelectorAll("mark")
    ).map((el: HTMLElement) => fromEvent(el, "click").pipe(map(_ => el["id"])));

    obs$.forEach(obs =>
      obs.pipe(takeUntil(this.closed$)).subscribe({
        next: id => {
          console.log(id);
        }
      })
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.closed$.next();
  }
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sjsgzd?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks, for this looks very clear. It seems to be console.logging *MouseEvent* instead of the value `'my name is what'` in the demo.

Comment: There isn't a direct answer to this question. Note that we aren't using the `click` event binding in the `innerHTML` but rather creating a new binding. So you need some workaround to extract the string from the `innerHTML` inside the subscription.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing `this.showcaseContentText.nativeElement.querySelector('mark').id;`